# Regarding editing the Tag Wikis excerpts

Tags: discussion, badges

Does just editing the Tag Wiki excerpt count as a whole Tag Wiki edit that counts towards the Research Assistant badge?

EDIT:

In view of the answer below, I checked today, after two of my Tag Wiki excerpts got approved, and this was displayed:

> Your Badge Progress
>    Research Assistant
>   0 tag wiki edits (0% done)

Comment: This probably belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com rather than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>[Yes, they do.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/178438)</s> <sup>(there was a rather major typo here :/)</sup>

[No, they do not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/new-silver-badge-for-editing-n-tag-wikis/121484#121484)

Comment: See Edit I've made.

Comment: @Bidella dunno about that, think that double edits count as two. I'll check.

Comment: @Bidella I'll ask at MSO for you, looks like this applies to wikis only and not excerpts (verifying from physics account)

Comment: @Bidella: Looks like they don't count, there was a typo in the meta question. [I fixed it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/68258/53)

Comment: From my own history I can confirm that excerpts do not count.